# Change Time Portion Only Of A DateTime Field With Case Statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am wanting to use a `case statement` to change the time piece only of a `datetime` field in `SQL Server 2008` I have a query that will change the time piece, but I need to know how to keep the date portion intact so only the time piece is altered.  Meaning  if the datetime is

> 01/01/2015 08:45:10.863

with my syntax I would want to alter it to

> 01/01/2015 08:30:00.000

This is my syntax which as I said will change the time portion but it does not retain the date.  How can I keep the date and change the time portion only?

```
Create Table #Test
(
    [charactername] varchar(100)
    ,[lefttabletime] datetime
)

Insert Into #Test Values
('Bob Goblin', '01/01/2015 08:14:23.000'),
('Grab Crab', '01/01/2015 08:30:56.023'),
('Mike Knight', '01/01/2015 08:45:10.863')

Select 
[charactername]
,case when CAST([lefttabletime] As TIME) > '08:40:00.000' THEN '08:30:00.000'     
else [lefttabletime]
FROM #Test

Drop Table #Test
```

**EDIT Additional Syntax Attempted**
This threw an error of:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

And I tried this syntax

```
Select 
[charactername]
,case when CAST([lefttabletime] As TIME) > '08:40:00.000' 
THEN CAST(CAST(CONVERT(DATE, [lefttabletime],101) AS VARCHAR) 
+ '08:40:00.000' AS DATETIME) else [lefttabletime] end
FROM #Test
```

Comment: What's the complete logic to be implemented here? Is it merely "any time within the last third of an hour should be replaced with `30` minutes" or are there other conditions to include here?

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier if you split the `leftabletime` into a date and a time component first, the recombine them with the new time portion:

```
;WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT  charactername,
                [date] = CAST(lefttabletime as date),
                [time] = CAST(lefttabletime as time)
        FROM    #test
    )

SELECT  charactername,
        CAST([date] as datetime)
        + CAST(CASE WHEN [time] > '08:40:00' THEN '08:30:00' ELSE [time] END as datetime)
FROM    cte
```

You can merge the two statement together but I like the simplicity and clarity that a separate CTE provides.

Answer (score 1):

I usually try to make datetime rounding problems fit the `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pattern, and I've managed to do that here:

```
Create Table #Test
(
    [charactername] varchar(100)
    ,[lefttabletime] datetime
)

Insert Into #Test Values
('Bob Goblin', '2015-01-01T08:14:23.000'),
('Grab Crab', '2015-01-01T08:30:56.023'),
('Mike Knight', '2015-01-01T08:45:10.863')

select charactername,
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(minute,'20010101',lefttabletime)%60 >= 40 THEN 
        DATEADD(minute,((DATEDIFF(minute,'20010101',lefttabletime)/30)*30),'20010101')
    ELSE lefttabletime END
from #Test

Drop Table #Test
```

The expression `DATEADD(minute,((DATEDIFF(minute,'20010101',lefttabletime)/30)*30),'20010101')` rounds the time of a `datetime` down to the nearest 30 minutes (`20010101` is an arbitrary date and doesn't need to be adjusted in any way).

I also just use a separate `DATEDIFF` to find the required matching condition. Where possible, with `datetime` data, I try to keep it in `datetime` variables, or, at worst, `int`s. As soon as you convert to strings you have to start worrying about formats, etc, which I'd usually rather avoid.

Result:

```
charactername
--------------------- -----------------------
Bob Goblin            2015-01-01 08:14:23.000
Grab Crab             2015-01-01 08:30:56.023
Mike Knight           2015-01-01 08:30:00.000
```